# Getting No Such Method Error while calling an API to display image

Tags: flutter

I am trying to call the API from coin gecko to display images of the crypto coin, current price, trend over the last 24 hours (through spark line chart) and the change in percentage in last 24 hours.

**[Current Error]**  (https://i.stack.imgur.com/axsFN.png).

**Here is the actual result**

```
[A table for data stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvva7.png).
[Error in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcglS.png).
[API Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wlra0.png).
[CoinModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiqS4.png).
[Item Constructor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBZKg.png).
[Flutter Doctor State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWgV3.png).
```